# Top Enterprise Level CMS not platform specific

Tags: content-management-system

I'm looking for some leads on Enterprise level CMS.  The platform doesn't matter.  I already have a handle on the majors in the .Net field and need to find some in the php, ruby, python, etc, fields.  For .NET I am looking at Sitecore, Ektron, and Kentico.  Ideally the CMS should have an open api, integrated search (lucene?), robust permissions, inline editing, content selection based on user segmentation, forums, blogs, ecommerce, and business user generated forms.  Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "looking for some leads"? I can tell you right away that if you speak to salesmen/consultants for any of the CMS that you've mentioned, they will all persuade you that their solution does all of those things. It will help us to answer your question if you narrow it down.

Comment: Yes and they have.  I know that we can build what we need using the above mentioned CMS(s).  They are all microsoft technology stacks.  I've been asked to see what is out there that is not built on top of microsoft technologies.  So by leads I mean the names of non-microsoft technology stack Enterprise CMS.

Comment: One more thing to add, I think you are missing two important .NET driven solutions: EPIServer and Sitefinity.

Comment: CodeWorks, you are definitely correct about EpiServer and Sitefinity, (even SDL Tridion as Albert mentioned).  The ones I listed in my question were the ones we narrowed down to in the .Net arena.

Comment: Just came across this, but you've probably seen it already: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems

Comment: Yes I have seen it.  a bit overwhelming in scope.  Do you have any experience with some of the cms listed?

Answer (score 2):

[SDL Tridion](http://www.sdl.com/en/wcm/) does all the things you described.

Comment: Yes, but it is a .Net product.  Specifically I am looking for non-.Net CMS to compare with the ones listed in my question.

Comment: @frjames - Just to clarify - SDL Tridion is not strictly a .NET product. The content manger itself runs on a windows server and does utilize some .NET technology. However, on the website side of things, most customers build their sites with a Java stack in Unix type environments rather than using .NET. So in brief , you can pretty much choose your preferred technology platform and programming technology if you choose to work with Tridion